# What is the proper way to merge to master?

Tags: git

Say I have a develop branch with 10+ commits that can be squashed down to one. I go to GitHub and do a "Squash and Merge" and it gives me the option to delete my branch. I want to keep this "develop" branch for other updates but now this branch is considered **Ahead of master**. What do I do in this case? If I delete it, how do I create a new branch with the same name without messing things up?

Comment: You could merge the develop branch into master without deleting the develop branch every now and then. Check out [giflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow).

Comment: If it's just you, consider a soft reset of those  commits and create a new commit, `git reset HEAD~10 && git commit`. This changes history and you would need to force push to GH development branch.  And then have GH merge that commit into master.

Answer (score 1):

As [the Git FAQ states](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#long-running-squash-merge), you don't want to keep two long-running branches where you merge one into the other with squash merges because this can only result in merge conflicts and sadness.

If you want to keep using the same branch (`develop`) for your PRs, then you can recreate the branch on the local side off of `master` with `git checkout -B develop master`.  However, if you do that, you will need to force push the `develop` branch unless you've deleted it from the remote first with `git push -d origin develop` or through the interface.

Alternatively, you can use regular merge commits and the problems outlined in the Git FAQ will go away, and you can keep using the `develop` branch essentially indefinitely.

Comment: You may want to specify that your first sentence only applies when squashing commits.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Long-running branches, where one of them is merged multiple times into another, constitute something of an anti-pattern in Git. This is one of the reasons why the original [Git flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) was so surprising; it uses that pattern.

If you think about how merge works, you can see what the problem is. A merge commit revolves around the *merge base*, which roughly speaking is the commit from which both branches originally split. When you squash merge `develop` into `master` and keep `develop` alive, the merge base doesn't move. Thus every merge after that is going to have to take account of all those same commits plus all the new commits on both sides, including your squash commit on `master`. This means you'll keep getting further and further ahead and behind, plus there is increased likelihood of a merge conflict.

One solution is: Don't do that. Just merge and then delete the `develop` branch. Now create a new `develop` branch off of the new end of `master` and away you go. Remember, a branch is incredibly lightweight; it is nothing but a name for a single commit. Destroying and creating the name is no trouble at all.

If you do decide to keep `develop` alive, then for heaven's sake don't use squash-and-merge. It is *not* a merge! It creates a commit on `master` out of whole cloth, bearing no topological relation whatever to `develop`. You have thus destroyed history completely, both for yourself and for Git.

So my advice would be, if you *must* keep `develop` alive, use *true* merges. Then, the next time, just before you merge `develop` into `master`, do a reverse merge where you merge `master` into `develop`. The result is that you move the merge base forward, plus you have an opportunity to grapple with any merge conflicts *before* doing the forward merge.

Comment: You might want to read my blog post about this: https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/